# Whats the best way via ImageOptimize to include images?

Tags: plugin-imageoptimize

I have a question regarding the *ImageOptimize* Plugin... if i upload image files which have like 400kb... after the plugin processed them sometimes they have more kb then before! (Size settings etc are the same as the original image... i set the quality to the maximum cause also otherwise the image quality looks very poor than the original) any tips maybe? Also sometimes my images load very long on my website... what could be the case? you can also take a look of course: https://marcelboer.com/ - General: Whats the best way nowadays to include srcsets on the website with webp images etc... still lazyloading or using the loading="lazy" tag without external lazyloading libarys... whats your experience?